# CRNA/Expo and iOS - how do i create a build signed with a Developer certificate?

Tags: ios, react-native, appium, expo, create-react-native-app

We're looking to run UI Automation on our app generated with CRNA using Appium.  I am able to generate an Enterprise Distribution build via the CRNA CLI but not a Developer build.  Is there a way to do this with the built-in CLI or a custom script?  If not, do I need to eject the app just to generate a Developer build?

Answer (score 0):

Its possible and thats how actually mobile device clouds are able to run tests on different iOS apps (not having their provision profiles):

More or less its like this:

1. You have MyApp.ipa
2. unzip MyApp.ipa
3. rm -rf Payload/MyApp.app/_CodeSignature/
4. cp ~/ Payload/MyApp.app/
5. codesign -f -s "iPhone Distribution: Company Certificate" Payload/MyApp.app
6. zip -qr resigned.ipa Payload/

What you need to know is that after resign you push notifications (if there are any) will be broken.